# Stored Procedure which accept xml file as input

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, xml, stored-procedures

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I have xml file as above.

In my SQL Server 2008 database there is table `Book__Master` In which all the columns are same as elements in above xml file i.e. there are columns like `bookid`, `author`, `title` etc.

Now I want to write a stored procedure which accepts this xml file as input parameter and stores the element's values as it is in their respective columns.

Can anyone help me on this that how I can write this type of stored procedure?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment...

Answer (score 7):

You can use X-Query for that:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d527c/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ParseXML
   @XML XML
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT 
    Book.value('@id','NVARCHAR(100)') AS id,
    Book.value('author[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS author,
    Book.value('title[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS title,
    Book.value('price[1]','DECIMAL(10,4)') AS price,
    Book.value('publish_date[1]','DATE') AS publish_date

    FROM @XML.nodes('catalog/book')Catalog(Book)

RETURN;
END;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @FileXML XML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer''s Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>';

EXEC dbo.ParseXML @FileXML;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d527c/1/0)**:

```
|    ID |               AUTHOR |                 TITLE | PRICE | PUBLISH_DATE |
|-------|----------------------|-----------------------|-------|--------------|
| bk101 | Gambardella, Matthew | XML Developer's Guide | 44.95 |   2000-10-01 |
| bk102 |           Ralls, Kim |         Midnight Rain |  5.95 |   2000-12-16 |
```

This shows you how to get to the values. From there you can easily insert them into your table.